# Retrieving SignalR connectionId on Web API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr

I have the following constellation:

I am using a asp.net core web api project which also includes a HubContext. The first thing a user has to do is to make an api call to my `UsersController : BaseController`. Here he/she calls the `api/login` route passing the according credentials. The return value of the `Login()` function is a JwtBearerToken, which the user from then on uses for all other api calls.

Once the token has been issued, the user (Client) establishes a SignalR connection over my `ConnectionHub : Hub`.

So far everything works well, the user gets authenticated using the token when calling api methods and I also can track the according Session state inside the scope of my `ConnectionHub`.

Now I have to retrieve the users (SignalR) session id whenever he/she makes an api call.

i. e. When the user calls a method in my `UsersController` I want to do something like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<User>> GetAll()
{
    // Here I want to retrieve the (SignalR) session id of the user calling this method.
    return Ok( userRepository.GetAllUsers() );
}
```

So far the only idea I have is to make the user send his SignalR-SessionId with the according api call, but what I'd like to achieve is to read the Id on the server side. How can I achieve this?

Comment: there's a fundamental difference between how `REST` works vs the `signalR` or sockets, I'd suggest do some reading on that and reconsider your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2), it is not possible to get the user's `connectionId` outside the hub (e.g. in a controller):

> When hub methods are called from outside of the Hub class, there's no caller associated with the invocation. Therefore, there's no access to the `ConnectionId`, `Caller`, and `Others` properties.

---

However, you can get the users with JavaScript by calling a hub method. Here you have access to the `connectionId` and to the database using your repository (make sure it is available via Dependency Injection).

I don't know what you want to do with the user's exactly, but you can simply return the users in the hub method and do something with the `connectionId`.

**YourHubClass.cs**

```
public Task GetAllUsers()
{
    // Get the ConnectionId
    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    // Get the users list
    var users = userRepository.GetAllUsers(); 

    // ...

    return Clients.User(user).SendAsync("UserListRequested", users);
}
```

Comment: Basically I want to know which session is/was responsible for an api call. In my scenario A single user can open several sessions, therefor I have to know in which session the user made a certain api call.

Comment: I'd suggest calling a hub method (explained above), because you cannot get the `connectionId` in a controller. As @Aarif commented to your question, there is a difference between REST and Websockets. The only way to get the `connectionId` is to use the HubContext.